# WCF large file upload causes CommunicationObjectFaultedException in 1 second

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class structure as a WCF request with many properties. One of the properties is a byte[], that holds a file to be uploaded to the server. Depending on the uploaded file it can be quite big, sometimes as big as 1.5 GB.
My WCF call is working fine while the byte[] remains under approx. 250 MB. However, if the uploaded file is bigger than 250 MB, I receive the following exception 1 second(!) after the call is initiated:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace:     
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
```

I use `NetTcpBinding`, but the phenomena remains with `BasicHttpBinding` and `WSHttpBinding` as well. I have all message size related parameters set to `int32.MaxValue` on the bindings.

I'd like to use streaming for upload, but then I could only have a single `Stream` parameter in the call, which will not work.

What could cause this behavior? I was thinking of a timeout issue, but no timeouts are explicitly set, and no timeouts default to 1 second (the shortest default is 1 minute).

**UPDATE:**
Configuration is made via code, not app.config. Here are the settings for both client and server:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.MaxConnections = 1000;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ListenBacklog = 128;

binding.PortSharingEnabled = false;
binding.TransactionFlow = false;

binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```

Comment: Could you share the configuration files (client and server)?

Comment: Sure, see update.

Comment: There is also one setting that you should try to set, but I don't know where is set in code, but here is the configuration file tags:
`<system.web><httpRuntime executionTimeout="4800" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/></system.web>`